# Как объект list преобразовать в картинку?

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, pillow

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
darkness=[[[[0] for x in range(3)] for x in range(32)] for x in range(32)]
darkness=numpy.ndarray(darkness)
darkness=Image.fromarray(darkness)
```

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

В общем, если это невозможно, был бы рад узнать, как можно по-другому самостоятельно задать цвета пикселей картинки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np

darkness = np.zeros((32, 32, 3), dtype="uint8")
img = Image.fromarray(darkness)
```

или используя список, хотя это не очень эффективно:

```
darkness=[[[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(32)] for x in range(32)]
data = np.asarray(darkness, dtype="uint8")
img = Image.fromarray(data)
```

Comment: Спасибо!Простите за долгое игнорирование,интернет на время пропал